# Add new timezone to moment.js timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I have to add "Asia/Bangkok" (ICT) to moment.js, as it doesn't seem to support it by default.

After loading moment.js and moment-timezone.js I tried defining this specific timezone following [this example](https://gist.github.com/coryschires/6236126):

```
moment.tz.add({
    "zones": {
        "Asia/Bangkok": [
            "6:42:4 - LMT 1880 6:42:4",
            "6:42:4 - BMT 1920_3 6:42:4",
            "7 - ICT"
        ],
    }
});

var currentTimeString = moment().tz('Asia/Bangkok').format('DD MMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss');
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> "Moment Timezone has no data for Asia/Bangkok. See
>   http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/."

Any ideas why?

Comment: Perhaps the documentation is better: [*Adding a Zone*](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/adding-a-zone/).

Comment: Yes, that's where I started, but the config format is not very well explained, I didn't find an easy to understand example how to construct the zone data `'America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|01010101010|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0'` for a custom time zone like ICT

Comment: You can use the [*pack*](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-utilities/pack/) method. I think the data format in your OP is wrong, the unpacked format is explained here: [*http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-formats/unpacked-format/*](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-formats/unpacked-format/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I want to post my solution, for others struggling with the badly documented API of moment.js...

To create a time zone, you will have to create an unpacked timezone object:

```
var unpacked = {
    name    : 'Asia/Bangkok',
    abbrs   : ['ICT'],
    untils  : [null],
    offsets : [-420]
};
```

*Note that while ITC is UTC+7 the UTC offset in the array has to be the additive inverse (negative) of 7*60 = 420 for some reason.*

Before you can use it, you will also have to pack this object, and for that you need to include moment-timezone-utils.js

`var packed = moment.tz.pack(unpacked);`

It will spit out the packed timezone format partly encoded in Base 60:
`Asia/Bangkok|ICT|-70|0|`

Now it can be added:
`moment.tz.add('Asia/Bangkok|ICT|-70|0|');`

If you don't want to go through all this trouble, there is also a [pre-packed file on GitHub](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json), where you can pick the needed timezone.

Comment: How do you use that pre-packed file?

Comment: i am gettinng `moment.tz.pack is not a function`. which version are you using? mine is `moment-timezone: ^0.5.28`